# Displaying the result of ML model on Web page

Tags: javascript, python, rest

I am exploring RESTful Flask API and as a learning I have created a small web form in HTML. Please see below the code for HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<h2>User Input</h2>
<body
<script>
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="/static/js/predict.js"></script>
<p>Please enter the Power prices per unit</p>

<form method="get" action='/predict' target ="_blank" 
enctype="multipart/form-data">
 New Value - 1:<br>
  <input type="number" id="New_val_1">
  <br>
  New Value - 2:<br>
  <input type="number" id="New_val_2">
  <br><br>
  <button id="btnpredict" type="button">Predict</button>

</form> 

<p>If you click the "Submit" button, the form-data will be sent to a page 
called "/action_page.php".</p>

</body>
</html>'
```

Please see below the code for predict.js. This is a JQuery AJAX

```
$(function(){
$('#btnpredict').click(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: '/predict',
        data: JSON.stringify({userInput: uInput})
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json', 
        success: function(response){
            ("#results").text(response.results);
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
});
```

And finally, the app.py code where the above HTML is getting rendered and upon receiving the the values passed on forms ML model is used.

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, request, render_template,json, Response
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
from sklearn.externals import joblib

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/predict', methods = ['GET'])
def predict():
     if request.method=='GET':
         X_value_new_1 = request.values.get('New_val_1') 
         X_value_new_2 = request.values.get('New_val_2')
         X_1,X_2 = X_value_new_1,X_value_new_2
         testData = np.array([X_1,X_2]).astype(np.float).reshape(-1,1)
         testData=sm.add_constant(testData)
         pred = Regression_model.predict(testData)
         dump = json.dumps({'prediction':list(pred)})
         resp = Response(dump,mimetype='application/json')
     return resp
   return None

def load_model():
    global Regression_model
    Regression_model = joblib.load('E:/model_file_save')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("**Starting Server...")

    load_model()

    app.run(debug=True)
```

Now the problem:
When I click on Predict button nothing happens. However, if on the address-bar if I write the 'http://localhost:5000/predict?New_val_1=1000&New_val_2=2000' then I get the correct prediction values in JSON format.

How to fix this issue? Is there any problem in JQuery? 
Please help.

Best
AR

Comment: could u tell what is "uInput" in your ajax method, I think you are not passing the input values to the request.

Answer (score 0):

```
Read textbox values e.g. $("#tag").val() and concate with ajax url e.g. 
predict?New_val_1=1000&New_val_2=2000'
and remove data property. You can also pass values using data property see below link for example.
```

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/870797/How-to-pass-textbox-value-to-other-page-using-Jque